# Divergent or Convergent for $(-1)^n$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I'm having trouble with two problems relating to this.
$$
A_n = {(-1)^n(n^3-5)\over 5n^3+n^2+1}
$$
I thought it was convergent because the absolute value of An goes to .2

Also,
$$
A_n = (-1)^n\sin\left(\frac{-1}{n}\right)
$$
I also think it is convergent due to the same reason as above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1st one is divergent. Just divide numerator and dinominator by $n^3$ and observe that the limit of the sequence oscillates between $\frac{1}{5}$ and $-\frac{1}{5}$.

2nd one is convergent as for sufficiently large $n$, $\sin (\frac{1}{n}) \approx \frac{1}{n}$ and hence the limit tends to zero.

Answer (score 0):

> -

Part one: "value of $A_n$ goes to .2".

-- This proves that series $\ \sum A_n\ $ is
divergent.

> -

Part two: however, series
$\ \sum_{n=1}\,(-1)^n\cdot\sin(-\frac 1{n})\ $ converges because its terms approach $\ 0,\ $ and
their absolute values are decreasing.

> PS. The argument from another Answer, about "*sandwich theorem*" is wrong because there was no "*sandwich*" there.
>
> PPS. That "another Answer" has been removed (possibly by its author).

Answer (score 0):

The first is divergent.  $\mid A_n\mid\to .2$, but the sign alternates.

The second one can be shown to converge to $0$.  (For instance,  $\sin x$ is continuous.)